# VBA Excel Msgbox keeps coming out when clicking on any other cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have the Msgbox set in my Excel sheet b the following code:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Range("D32").Value > 12 And Range("D32").Value < 25 Then
 VBA.MsgBox "Remember to double up on cable lengths and DP's", , "THP Between 13 & 24"
 End If

 End Sub
```

it works, but pop-ups every time when I clik on any other cell in my worksheet.

I tried to sort this out by using this thread:

[VBA MsgBox keeps coming back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079634/vba-msgbox-keeps-coming-back)

and my code was looking like this:

```
  If Range("D32").Value > 12 And Range("D32").Value < 25 Then
         If MsgBox("Remember to double up on cable lengths and DP's", , "THP Between 13 & 24") Then
        Application.Undo
        End If
   End If
```

but it didn't work.

I found also other solutions here:

http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?35907-Solved-display-msgbox-once

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-to-display-msgbox-only-once.806009/

stackoverflow.com/questions/49072954/vba-msgbox-show-only-once

but they weren't helpful.

Is there any way to make it work? I would like to have this msgbox appear just once.

Comment: You have to test the `Target` parameter to see if it is a cell that you want to pop-up for.  You are only testing the values of 2 specific cells.

Comment: I have already target set 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811227/how-to-use-the-target-parameter-in-a-standard-module

Comment: The code you have posted is not testing the `Target` parameter.  *You* are not supposed set `Target`, the event `Worksheet_SelectionChange` sets it for you and passes it to you.  The `Target` parameter indicates the range of the new selection.  The `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event fires for *every* selection change in the worksheet, so you have to test the `Target` parameter to see if it is in the range(s) that you want to handle and exit/skip if it is not.  As your link indicates you could also check the `ActiveCell` global variable, but you are not doing that either in your posted code.

Comment: @RBarryYoung thanks for clarification. I need to study this bit for the future.

Answer (score 1):

The correct code should be like this:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D32,D33")) Is Nothing Then

    If Range("D32").Value > 12 And Range("D32").Value < 25 Then
        VBA.MsgBox "Remember to double up on cable lengths and DP's", , "THP Between 13 & 24"
    End If

End If
```

If we want to have the msgbox appear just once, we have to set the range of intersection. This range surely will be restricted to our target cell and optionally the next cell underneath.

Obviously as said in the comment below, we must enclose everything within:

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
```

https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-forum/vba-macros/message-box-should-appear-only-once-when-spreadsheet-is-opened